# Selenium JSExecutor - Get value from Amcharts bar bubble

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, amcharts

I am trying to get the value using a JSExecutor with Selenium from an Amcharts bar graph.  The bar graph is in a similar format, where when i point with my mouse the bubble will display the value.

[image: Amcharts Bar Graph]

My HTML DOM is in this format:

```
   <div class="amcharts-chart-div" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 1315px; height: 500px; padding: 0px;">
      <svg version="1.1" style="position: absolute; width: 1315px; height: 500px; left: -0.421875px; top: 0.3125px;">
         <desc>JavaScript chart by amCharts 3.12.3</desc>
        <g><path cs="100,100" d="M0.5,0.5 L1314.5,0.5 L1314.5,499.5 L0.5,499.5 Z" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0"></path>
  <path cs="100,100" d="M0.5,0.5 L1218.5,0.5 L1218.5,443.5 L0.5,443.5 L0.5,0.5 Z" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0" transform="translate(76,20)"></path></g>
        <g><g transform="translate(76,20)"><g><path cs="100,100" d="M122.5,0.5 L122.5,5.5" fill="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" transform="translate(0,443)"></path>
```

The bar with the value that i am looking for has the following xpath:

```
//*[@id="barGraph"]/div/div/svg/g[6]/g/g[3]/path
```

I tried using:

```
String str = "document.querySelector(\"#barGraph > div > div > svg > g:nth-child(7) > g > g:nth-child(3) > path\")";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
System.out.println(js.executeScript(str));
```

but i am getting back a null value. How can i correctly do this?

Comment: you are not returning anything in the js. Try adding `return ` at the beginning of of your current js in `str`.

Answer (score 0):

try with the below CSS and then update the type number based on requirement.

```
#barGraph div > div > svg > g:nth-of-type(1) path
```